# Remove " from string

Tags: python, string, list

```
with open("p022_names.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        name=[str(v) for v in line.split(",")]
name.sort()
print(name)
tot=0
for i in range(len(name)):
    tot=tot+sum(ord(letter)-64 for letter in name[i])
print(tot)
```

While reading data from files it is also adding " and ' into the name.
If the name is COLIN it is saved in the list name as '"COLIN"'.
How do I fix it?
Input file.

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL","RUTH","SHARON","MICHELLE","LAURA","SARAH","KIMBERLY","DEBORAH","JESSICA","SHIRLEY","CYNTHIA","ANGELA","MELISSA","BRENDA","AMY","ANNA","REBECCA","VIRGINIA","KATHLEEN","PAMELA","MARTHA","DEBRA","AMANDA","STEPHANIE","CAROLYN","CHRISTINE","MARIE","JANET","CATHERINE","FRANCES","ANN","JOYCE","DIANE","ALICE","JULIE","HEATHER","TERESA","DORIS","GLORIA","EVELYN","JEAN","CHERYL","MILDRED","KATHERINE","JOAN","ASHLEY","JUDITH","ROSE","JANICE","KELLY","NICOLE","JUDY","CHRISTINA","KATHY","THERESA","BEVERLY","DENISE","TAMMY","IRENE","JANE","LORI","RACHEL","MARILYN","ANDREA","KATHRYN","LOUISE","SARA","ANNE","JACQUELINE","WANDA","BONNIE","JULIA","RUBY","LOIS","TINA","PHYLLIS","NORMA","PAULA","DIANA","ANNIE","LILLIAN","EMILY","ROBIN","PEGGY","CRYSTAL","GLADYS","RITA","DAWN","CONNIE","FLORENCE","TRACY","EDNA","TIFFANY","CARMEN","ROSA","CINDY","GRACE","WENDY","VICTORIA",
```

Output
['"MARY"','"..."','"..."',..]

Comment: Can you provide a few lines from your input file as an example? Does the input file have quotes around the strings? Where do you see the quotes that you want to remove?

Comment: If this is a CSV file, you should *not* try and remove the quotes manually, but use the `csv` module to parse it properly.

Comment: Also, please show the output from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove these characters from your string you could probably do something like this:

`s = s.replace("\"","")`

This replaces all instances of `"` with an empty string.

If you only want them to be removed on the ends of the string, you can do this

`s = s.strip("\"")`

If you want to make sure you're only removing one quote from each end, you can do something like this:

```
if s.startswith("\""):
    s = s[1:]
elif s.endswith("\""):
    s = s[:-1]
```

If you know the string will always have the quotes, you can simplify it to this:

```
s = s[1:-1]
```

However this file appears to be a csv file, and it is much better to parse these files using the `csv` lib.

Comment: But what if the data contains `'`? That would remove the quotes as well!

Comment: "But why is it adding " and ' while reading from the file." The `"` comes directly from the input file. When you see `['"COLIN"']` for example, the `'` is to indicate that this is a list of strings. It is **not** an actual character in the string.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I fxed this in the recent edit, after I saw the input data

Comment: @Qwerty That explanation was primarily for the OP and any future visitors.

Comment: It is txt file not csv.

Comment: The file extension does not matter, it is still in the format of csv @ShikharDwivedi

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first and last characters from a string in Python by:

```
name = "'COLIN'"
print(name[1:-1])
```

This will print 
`COLIN`
instead of
`'COLIN'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It supports multiple names in line separated by comma, also multiple lines in file.

```
names = []
with open('p022_names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        names.extend(v.lower().strip('"').strip("'") for v in line.split(","))

names.sort()

for name in names:
    tot = sum(ord(letter)-96 for letter in name)
    print("{0}: {1}".format(name, tot))
```

Comment: Note you don't need `str(v)`. Just `v` should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("p022_names.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        name=[str(v) for v in line.split(",")]
name.sort()
print(name)
```

I assume that you see something like this:

```
['"MARY"','"PATRICIA"'...]
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove both the `'` and teh `"` characters. The `'` characters are here to indicate that the elements of the list are strings. **You do not have any of these in your actual data.** You only need to remove the double quotes. You don't need to worry about the single quotes. The only quotes you have are the `"` ones that were read from the file.

Also, you can simplify

```
name=[str(v) for v in line.split(",")]
```

to

```
name = line.split(",")
```

Comment: But I also need to find sum of all letters in name[i]. if name[i]="abc" it should add 6 to tot.

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi Why should it add 6 and not 3?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I assume index of the letter in the alphabet: `1+2+3`

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi Your summing code appears to be correct, so I do not address it here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to find out sum of all the letters present in the string like a=1 b=2 c=3 so a+b+c=1+2+3=6.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No, it doesn't add index but the position of the letter in alphabetical order a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4..... y=24. z=25.

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi The index is the position. Also wouldnt y and z be 25 and 26?

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi Your summing code appears to be correct, so keep it as-is.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I got my answer, only issue was " in name which I fixed changing name=[str(v) for v in line.split(",")] to name=[str(v.strip('"')for v in line.split(",")]

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi Great! Note that the `str()` call is unnecessary.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice so name=[v.strip('"') for v in line.spli()] will work the same?

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi Yes it should. Note that `v` is already a string and `v.strip('"')` returns a string.